# Plesk (or similar) admin panel for NodeJS hosting

Tags: nginx, node.js, control-panel

I am wondering if there any Plesk-like control panels to offer NodeJS hosting.

I am trying to find out if it is possible to replace Apache and PHP with NodeJS and NGINX for vhosts, while MySQL management, mail servers and such are all managed by one panel. So far I have not been able to find software like this.

If this isn't available, I'm wondering why it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any control panel that has NodeJS and Nginx builtin installers, but you can use Nginx and NodeJS on cPanel without any issues with or without the use of plugins.

You can install Nginx either manually, or through cPanel plugin Nginx Admin, it will allow you to control the service and vhosts trough WHM web panel.

http://www.nginxcp.com/

For NodeJS install follow these steps.

Make sure that following are installed, which they should by default on cPanel servers.

```
GCC 4.2 or newer
Python 2.6 or 2.7
GNU Make 3.81 or newer
```

Download and install NodeJS

- wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
- tar -xvf  node-latest.tar.gz
- cd node-v*
- ./configure
- make
- make install

These are the steps that work on most cPanel server.

You can find multiple NodeJS install instructions on web, here is one
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/javascript/install-nodejs

Also alternative to that, you can use nDeploy, also cPanel plugin, but not a free one. 
I haven't tried it, but according to their site, it is "cpanel nginx plugin that lets you deploy PHP/Ruby/Python/NodeJS/ColdFusion and more!"

http://ndeploy.in/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm specifically looking for something that is written for NodeJS, not allowing support through modules. I have nginx and NodeJS working fine, but it is a pain to configure mail, mysql, dns, NodeJS and nginx on different places every time I want to add a site

Comment: when you create a new domain in cPanel, vhosts will be automatically added to nginx when using http://www.nginxcp.com/, I am not sure about nDeploy, so MySQL,email,dns,and sites are all controlled through cPanel account which has the domain on it.